# How to get values over n minutes old on redis?

Tags: time, redis, key-value

I have redis datastore with data stored using alphanumeric non-date keys. How might I get the values that have been stored longer than a certain time period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the name of every key you add in a Sorted Set, with the score being the creation timestamp. To retrieve ranges, such as keys created before x time, refer to [`ZRANGE`](https://redis.io).